# Nifi maximum value omitting some records

Tags: apache-nifi

Have anyone faced the situation that `Nifi` ommits some records when using incremental refresh with maximum value? We foreseen the column which is used for maximum value some records are inserting not at the time when their col value states. Is there any way to investigate such situation?

Comment: What data type is the column you're using for maximum value? It should be a timestamp with at least millisecond precision.

Comment: @mattyb it is date time column

Comment: What DB? Does the datetime type support millisecond precision? What is the Run Schedule of the processor?